# Can't connect to any ntp server from windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, time, ntp

I have three windows computers that I'm trying to sync to an NTP server. All of them fail to do so. I have confirmed that the NTP server runs fine by connecting from WSL.

Here's what I've tried:

I have Enabled `windows time` in windows services.

I've tried `Control panel -> date and time -> internet clocks -> input server -> sync`. This fails

I've tried it in an elevated prompt:

```
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

This errors with: `The computer did not resync because no time data was available`

I've tried manual config:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:<ip> /syncfromflags:manual
```

This reports success but doesn't actually set the time...

I've tried turning it off and on again:

```
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

I've also tried restarting and every other combination of the above that I could find online, but I'm getting the same results.

I've tried to use `pool.ntp.org` and got the same result.

Then I've tried `telnet <ip> 123`, which reports that the server is unreachable.

`ping <ip>` works fine.

In WSL (ubuntu), `sudo ntpdate -q <ip>` works correctly.

I've disabled the firewall on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

There most likely is another firewall beyond your network, which attempts to statelessly block all *inbound* NTP requests (perhaps as some kind of DDoS prevention), but which results in also blocking certain types of NTP responses as well.

> Then I've tried `telnet <ip> 123`, which reports that the server is unreachable.

NTP runs exclusively over UDP; it doesn't use TCP.

> In WSL (ubuntu), `sudo ntpdate -q <ip>` works correctly.

NTP has two modes: client-server mode and symmetric mode. Somewhat unusually they're distinguished by UDP ports: client-server uses the typical model where the source port number is chosen randomly, whereas symmetric mode instead uses 123 as both the destination *and* source port (which is something you rarely, if ever, see in other protocols).

If you were to look at the actual packets in Wireshark, you would see that:

- `ntpdate` uses the client-server mode, so it sends packets from a random port; responses arrive to your system on that random port.
- Windows uses the symmetric mode, so it sends packets from port 123; this means responses from the server are being sent to port 123 on your side, making them look exactly like a *request* in the eyes of a stateless firewall.

Several ISPs are known for blocking the latter, e.g. I've found forum posts about AT&T being notorious for doing so.

I don't think you can change the way Windows Time Service works in this regard; your only options might be a) to run a tiny local NTP server for your LAN, which then syncs to some upstream NTP using a mode that isn't blocked; or b) run an external NTP server that would be accessed via IPsec or some kind of VPN.

---

(Sometimes this also depends on your router – many routers implement NAT in such a way that it *forcefully* changes the source port of UDP packets, so even if Windows does send packets from port 123, the ISP which does the blocking might never see that thanks to the router's NAT hiding it, and everything would appear to work perfectly fine.

On top of that, even routers that don't normally rewrite UDP source ports will still do so out of necessity when two computers try to talk to the same server, in which case it would appear to work for the 2nd computer only.)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. That clarifies a bunch of things. I'm not sure if it fixes my problem though, since I ran into this trying to use a local NTP server (on a Moxa EDS-510E-3GTXSFP switch). I only switched to online servers for debugging.